# Is high ponytail haram for women

Tags: clothing

As we all know that high bun is not allowed. Is high ponytail also not allowed as it does not look like the hump of the camel??

Comment: Can you provide a source saying having a high bun is haram ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not haram whether one has a ponytail, high low or midway.

What is haram is immodesty in public. Islam enjoins modesty in public as a religious obligation.